# Adding custom icon listing all documents and on click it should be added as link

Tags: wysiwyg, froala

I want to add custom icon to list all pdf docs from service and on clicking particular doc it should be added as link .on opening that link it should download file

Comment: What is your question on this? Did you try yet any approaches? Where did you get lost?

Comment: I want to show imagemanager kind of modal popup on click of custom icon.